# How do I process styles after a knockout computed method refreshes my view?

Tags: jquery-ui, templates, knockout.js

I have a problem in my KnockoutJS application that I can't seem to figure out. Basically, I've bound a list to a 'ko.computed' method which allows me to filter items from the main list. I use this list for my main display to the user. On each item in my template, I have one ore more buttons that I need to render as JqueryUI buttons. I can't seem to find the way to redraw the buttons correctly in my model once the computed triggers a change.

Here is a very (very) simple example of a mock view model:

```
function List(items) { 
  var self = this;
  self.allItems = ko.observableArray(items || []);
  self.search = ko.observable('');
  self.filtered = ko.computed(function(){
    var search = self.search();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.allItems(), function(item){
      return item == search;
    });
  });
}
```

My view might look like this:

```
Search: <input type='text' data-bind='value: search' />
<ul data-bind='foreach: filtered'>
  <li>
    <span data-bind='text: $data'> </span>
    <button>NOTICE</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is how I initialize the display:

```
$(function(){
  var vm = new List(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']);
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  $('button').button(); // <-- notice!
});
```

Note that everything works fine initially! I get the nice looking JqueryUI button when the page first displays... However, as soon as I enter **a** into the search box, the button loses it's style completely. I need to find a way to call `$('button').button()` again.

Is there an event or callback inside of Knockout.js that I could call to setup my ui buttons after the computed method is triggered?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the style is getting reset is because the dom element that the button was previously bound to has been destroyed.

You can solve this by creating a simple custom binding (not-tested)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uibutton = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element), config = valueAccessor();
        $element.button();
    }
}
```

This can be added to your template with this addition

```
<button data-bind="uibutton: {}">NOTICE</button>
```

You can remove the call to $('button').button();

When using KO we can almost do without standard Jquery expressions altogether, often custom bindings allow us to do the same but with the possibility of more advanced things like reacting to observables etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: "When using KO we can almost do without standard Jquery expressions altogether," is interesting for me. Would you care to updat/edit and elaborate, please?

Comment: Because KO allows us to decouple UI dom manipulation from our business logic we should be writing our models in way that remove the need for $("Bla") expressions, if we find we need to do something with the dom it's usually a call for a custom binding instead. Notice that the examples on the KO home page don't use $("Bla") selectors.